# How to use Chartjs on the server?

Tags: javascript, charts

The source code of Chart.js (specifically in `src/Chart.Core.js`) there is a comment

`// Declare root variable - window in the browser, global on the server`

I wonder how to use the code on the server?

I tried a simple script placed in the root directory of the cloned repository with the following content:

`require('./src/Chart.Core');`

...and I got this error:

`/Users/gabor/work/Chart.js/src/Chart.Core.js:732
            return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                   ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at /Users/gabor/work/Chart.js/src/Chart.Core.js:732:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gabor/work/Chart.js/src/Chart.Core.js:740:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gabor/work/Chart.js/src/Chart.Core.js:2201:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gabor/work/Chart.js/a.js:1:63)`

I am now confused. I am not even sure what do I expect where should it draw, but if the script I wrote is supposed to work then I think `window` might need to be replaced in the code by `root`.

Context: Actually my goal was to see if I can write a test for Chart.js that I could run with Node.js.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution to offer, but have you considered using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/nchart ?